# How to momentarily stop the execution of a loop that call an API n time? I need to wait that the previous API call is completed before call again

Tags: java, spring

I have the following doubt.

I have a **WSO2 ESB** application (basically you can see it as an application that expose an API that can be called and do something).

This application expose an API that do something (create an XML docuement and send it to another web service).

I have to build an external very simple Java application (I think a **Spring** application) that does the following things:

- Perform a query on a database and obtain n records (a lot of records).
- Iterate on these retrieved records and for each record perform a call to the API exposed by this **WSO2 ESB** application.

So if I have retrieved 10000 records, it will perform 10000 call to the API exposed by this **WSO2 ESB** application.

It seems pretty simple. There is only one constraint that this Java application have to keep: during the iteration it can't do a new call before that the WSO2 ESB application have terminated the work related to the previous record (I can't have multiple instance of the WSO2 ESB application at the same time).

So this **WSO2 ESB API** will return a status code (a message) to the Java application when it terminate its job.

What is a smart way to handle this kind of situation? Someone says to me to use a **lock file** in this way: When the Java application starts write a **lock file** in a directory. This lock file will be romeved after that it receives a confirmation from the web service.

I am not sure that this mechanism is neat.

What is a smart way to handle situation like this into an iteration? Spring offer me something to do it is a specific smart way?

Comment: Looks like it's enough to make the main method call synchronized. So any another request will wait till the execution end.

Comment: @StanislavL what exactly do you mean? What means that the "main method call synchronized"? Can you give me more details about it? So I will check on documentation